# old print and processing recipe

Tags: alt-process

I am a analog photographer and printer.
My main interest is in old printing processes.
I have a recipe book for processes that I (want to) master.
Can anybody give me guidance in old manuals and books?

For example:
Autochrome platemaking and development.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is too open-ended for this site, I'm afraid.  It's more of "idea generation" or a "list" question that something that can have one best answer.  Perhaps you can ask a single question about a single alternative process -- then we can likely answer it.

Comment: There's a great book about Autochromes that came out a few years ago. Take a look at ["The Lumière Autochrome: History, Technology, and Preservation"](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Lumiere_Autochrome.html?id=30gkBAAAQBAJ)

Comment: Particularly when it comes to autochrome platemaking, AFAIK, all recent attempts have more or less failed or at least not nearly been able to reproduce the colour fidelity of the plates from old times. It would though, of course, have been a very satisfying experience to make colour photographs with home made plates.